# Async checking when perform segue

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue, moya

My app has two ViewControllers, LoginViewController, MainViewController

In storyboard, I have created a segue from LoginViewController to MainViewController

And now I use Moya to implement the login function, but I want to keep the segue

So I write this function in LoginViewController

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    var ret = false
    let provider = MoyaProvider<MyApi>()
    provider.request(.login(username : inUsername.text! , password : inPassword.text! )) { result in
        switch result {
        case let .success(moyaResponse):
            let data = moyaResponse.data
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let user = try decoder.decode(Login.self, from: data)
                if(user.status == 1){
                    ret = true
                }else{
                    print(user.msg)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("error")
            }
        case let .failure(error):
            ret = false
        }
    }
    return ret
}
```

But moya request is async, this function will return before response, so this function never return true

How to make this work?

---

update:

Now I move the request to button IBAction, but it still not work

if I remove `shouldPerformSegue`, it still go to next viewcontroller before callback

if I return true in `shouldPerformSegue`, it will go to next viewcontroller even login fail

if I return false in `shouldPerformSegue`, it will not go to next viewcontroller even login success

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return true // always to next 
    return false // never to next 
}

@IBAction func clickLogin(_ sender: Any) {

    let provider = MoyaProvider<ZfuApi>()
    provider.request(.login(username : inUsername.text! , password : inPassword.text! )) { result in
        switch result {
        case let .success(moyaResponse):
            let data = moyaResponse.data
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let user = try decoder.decode(Login.self, from: data)
                if(user.status == 1){
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToMain", sender: sender)
                }else{
                    print(user.msg)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("error")
            }
        case let .failure(error):
            print(error.response?.description)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move this request to some login button handler. Once you get the status then perform `segue`.

Comment: Do the async request in the login button `IBAction`. When the request callback and login success, call `self.performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`

Comment: I added an answer based on the current implementation. Can you give it a try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use async method in shouldPerformSegue, but you can perform async method before performing segue and than call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` in completion block.

Comment: This is not work, now I move request to IBAction , but what should I return in `shouldPerformSegue`? if I return ture, it always go to next view, if I return false, it never go to next view

Comment: What @Ilya-Kharabet is suggesting is correct. `shouldPerformSegue` is best used to halt segues which have been programmatically defined in your storyboard file which would otherwise always execute, as you have noticed. An alternative is to define the segue in your storyboard not from a control to a new view controller, but from controller to controller, and which can then only be activated in code. Then, in your async code, you perform the check you would have put in `shouldPerformSegue()`. If it passes, you can then manually execute the segue by invoking it with `performSegue()`.

Comment: Now is ok, I just remove the button segue, and create a new segue from controller, then everything is work.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a property to perform the `segue` as below,

```
var isLoggedIn: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToMain", sender: self)
    }
}

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return isLoggedIn
}

@IBAction func clickLogin(_ sender: Any) {

    let provider = MoyaProvider<ZfuApi>()
    provider.request(.login(username : inUsername.text! , password : inPassword.text! )) { result in
        switch result {
        case let .success(moyaResponse):
            let data = moyaResponse.data
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let user = try decoder.decode(Login.self, from: data)
                if(user.status == 1){
                    self.isLoggedIn = true
                }else{
                    print(user.msg)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("error")
            }
        case let .failure(error):
            print(error.response?.description)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried, this is ok, but finally I use controller to controller segue, because it is better.

Comment: Exactly, that is the better approach.